# Including character that was used in the pattern search in the match

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
[?q]this is a test[?p]
<br>
[?q]this is a test<RANDOM_TAG>
```

I want to get all the text between `[?q]` and `[?p]` **OR** `[?q]` and `<`. But I want to keep the `<` in the match results.
I have this regex:

```
\[\?q\](.*?)(?:\[\?p\]|<)
```

But if I do a replace of the first group with AAA, i get this:

```
AAA
<br>
AAARANDOM_TAG>
```

I want this:

```
AAA
<br>
AAA<RANDOM_TAG>
```

[Regex link for demonstration](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=37feaa0f-a257-4528-9f41-d8230ee375d3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

change your regex to `/\[\?q\](.*?)(?:\[\?p\]|(?=<))/g` or try other regex i have mentioned below

```
var str = '[?q]this is a test[?p]\n<br>\n[?q]this is a test<RANDOM_TAG>';
var res = str.replace(/(\[\?q\].*?\[\?p\]|\[\?q\].*?(?=<))/g, 'AAA');
console.log(res);
```

I have used a positive lookahead to check if the value is followed by `<`

[**link to demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pT3vU3)

Answer (score 0):

It feels somewhat hacky, but you could add capturing for the optional `<` and include it in the replacement:

```
\[\?q\](.*?)(?:\[\?p\]|(<))
=>
<span class="query">$1</span>$2
```

http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=885c3c1b-b9b8-4d17-8e6a-ec90130d3e2f